# Google VR daydream how to do Constellation menu as elements sample showed?

Tags: google-vr

guys

I am trying google vr daydream and working on constellation menu now. I tried the offical demo that there are lots sub menu under the root menu once controller hover on , but in the root menu script object I only see 3 main sub nodes in the inspector.

now I am trying to do my own sub menu tree , is there any fast coding way to do this or must I  drag all sub menus to the inspector manually one by one?

Comment: Did you succeed in coding 1 sub-menu?

Comment: yes, yesterday I tried dynamic adding subtree ,it works ,but firstly I have to make "menutree" in ConstellationMenuRoot as public , then get the .tree property to add children , I dont know if anyother better way .